# Asp.Net Mvc shopping cart storing selected items in cart best approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, shopping-cart

I am trying to create a shopping cart application in Asp.Net Mvc3. I am confused to take correct decision while storing user selected items temporarily to cart. What would be the best approach to store cart items temporarily till check out process.

1. Temp table in database? Delete table once items are checked out
2. Sessions?
3. Tempdata?
4. Jquery Array?
5. Any Other way?

Please suggest.

Comment: in my practice I prefer Sessions. It much more lightweight than database. Sessions holds user info as much time as it needed.

Comment: TempData keep the information for the time of an HTTP Request. This mean only from one page to another. So, TempData can't be used for shopping cart

Comment: @simoco - sessions are great if you want to persist data from request to request.  However, if you are using In-Proc sessions with .NET and either a) the app pool recycles or b) you have a load balanced server cluster, you can expect your session to disappear randomly.

Comment: how about storing cart data in cookies? This way users can access their cart even if they come back to your site after days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I understand, you have two types of users:

- Authenticated
- Not authenticated

And few more scenarios possible:

- Right after the purchase, user can become authenticated.
- User can authenticate himself in the middle of the process (add one item to the cart, then authenticate, then add one more item)
- User is authenticated, and already may have something in the cart (added an item yesterday, for instance).
- User is not authenticated, but may already have an item in the cart added a month ago (you don't want to miss it, right?)

So I think the best approach is to have an entity `User` linked with entity `Cart` linked with entities `Item` like this:

```
User <--- one-to-one ---> Cart <--- one-to-many ---> Item
```

I recommend to use the following approach. Each time when the user clicks the button "Add to Cart" on your page, your javascript code must:

1. Get the variable (for instance, cart_id) from cookies
2. If cart_id is not found, obtain new cart_id via ajax call (`/Cart/GetNewId`), and add this variable to cookies.
3. Add an item to the cart via ajax call (`/Cart/AddItem`)

cart_id must be `Guid`.

This approach has several benefits:

- On the client you keep cart_id only.
- If the client closes the browser, he can come back in days, months or years (depending on cookie settings)
- You keep all important information in the database. It's not dependent on the server settings, you can migrate your server painless to different hosting provider, etc.
- When the user is not authenticated, the property `User` (inside of the `Cart` entity) is null. When user authenticates himself, you can easily assign existing cart with all existing items to the user by setting the `User` property only.

etc.

The answer to your question looks like closer to your "*Temp table in database? Delete table once items are checked out*". Moreover, it's more natural. Image yourself in the store, you have a temporary cart, you can put items into this cart while walking though the store, pay at the end, and delete everything from your shopping cart when you finish.

Compare this approach to Sessions:

- If the server goes down, session is lost. You have to use SQL persistence for sessions.
- If you use SQL, you have to use [aspnet_regsql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx). It will create additional tables only to keep your session data. Personally, I don't like them and I want to keep my database clean. I think sessions with SQL persistence are too generic-purpose.
- If you try to fetch some data for statistic purposes, it can become a pain. With my approach, you can easily do this.

Comment: What happens if the user has a cart_id and is authenticated. but then through another computer makes a new cart unauthenticated and then logs in. Now there are two carts for the same user.

Comment: This would be a brilliant feature of an application. Why younsay it as if it is bad?  :))

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution would be to use sessions.  Sessions already have the ability to maintain data from request to request without the need to extensively roll your own solution (database tables, custom cookies, etc).

However, since the default session setup is to use In-Proc (meaning stored in memory), you have to consider events such as the application pool recycling, how many users will be maintaining a cart at one time (extensive memory usage) or a load balanced server cluster (memory not shared between servers).

In order to mitigate these scenarios, switch your session provider to use SQL to store session data.  There is a little that needs to be done in order to [setup SQL session storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#sectionSection2), however, the data can be accessed by mulitple servers as well as persist in the event of an application pool recycle.

The steps that need to be performed are:

1. Setup sql server to work with sessions - `aspnet_regsql.exe -S ServerName -E -ssadd -sstype c -d DatabaseName`
2. Update your web.config appropriately

> Code

```
  <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <sessionState mode="SQLServer"
          sqlConnectionString="Your Sql Connection String" />
      </system.web>
    </configuration
```

>